# npm command not working after removing saws

Tags: npm

Running mac os 10.15.7. I installed aws-profile-switcher and it was working great https://github.com/devtanc/aws-profile-switcher
I wanted to try saws https://github.com/donnemartin/saws and I tried that but did not like it. So I uninstalled using 'pip uninstall saws' and after that most commands like ls, df,npm, pip do not work.. Can you please help.. I get this error message..

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@devtanc/aws-profile-switcher/switcher.js:88:25
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed @devtanc folder under /usr/local/lib/node_modules. now aws cli  working

Thanks